# How to clear a response entity object in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC Controller to handle web requests.

> code for DAO

```
public University findbyId(int id){
                try {
                    Connection con = JDBCConnection.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement s=con.prepareStatement(UniversitySQL.FINDBYID);
                    ResultSet rs;
                    s.setInt(1, id);
                    rs=s.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        uni=new University(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2));
                    }

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UniversityDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UniversityDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            return uni ;
    }
```

> Code for Servlet

```
@RequestMapping(value="/university/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUniversityById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    University uni = null;
    uni = university.findbyId(id);
    data.setData(uni);
    data.setMessage("Success");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(data.toString(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The problem is if I enter an invalid `id` it returns the last successful result instead it should return `null`.

Comment: You need to add more stuff, at least your repository (it is where university.findbyId(id), findById is)

Comment: @john check now

Comment: what is `data`? and why are you reusing it? also looks like you're using a variable in the controller to store `headers`.  Safer to not reuse any variables in your controller

Comment: Please, provide also UniversitySQL.FINDBYID. Did you debug rs=s.executeQuery(); ?